# Change the timezone in a terminal

Tags: date, timezone

I connect my web server via SSH Terminal on Mac.

```
cat /var/www/vhosts/example.com/statistics/logs/error_log
```

The Date of my server and local computer differs so output of error_logs is not efficient for me. Is it possible to change date output to my local time without modifying settings in server computer? The server date settings should stay same because another user is connecting from another part of world. I want to handle this automatically by Mac terminal if possible and just for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the timezone for your logged in session,then you can `export` the `TZ` variable to your required timezone.

For example:

```
export TZ=US/Eastern
```